# Adding [DataMember] [DataContract] attributes in Entity Framework POCO Template

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, poco, t4

I would like some help adding in a POCO .tt Entity Framework template Attributes to support WCF serialization and if its possible how to add namespace usings to each entity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to open your `model1.tt` file (or whatever it's called in your project), and add a few things.

Locate these lines of code (line 34, in my case):

```
// Emit Entity Types
foreach (EntityType entity in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
```

Just before this line here:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
```

you need to add the `[DataContract]` attribute:

```
[DataContract]
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
```

to your template.

Next, locate this line of code:

```
<#=PropertyVirtualModifier(Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty))#> <#=code.Escape(edmProperty.TypeUsage)#> <#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#>
```

Before that line, add the `[DataMember]` attribute to your template:

```
[DataMember]
<#=PropertyVirtualModifier(Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty))#> <#=code.Escape(edmProperty.TypeUsage)#> <#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#>
```

This will add those attributes for all entities and all properties - that might not be what you really want, but it's a start.

Also: to finish off, you probably want to have a look at the `WriteHeader` function in your T4 template, and add the `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` statement to your list of usings:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;  // add this to handle DataContract/DataMember
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i need, i think i might start understand T4 minute by minute, i just need some fixes quick right now. Please can you provide some help on where i add using namespaces on each entity?

Comment: @gtas: updated my answer - you'll need to include the extra namespace `System.Runtime.Serialization` to handle the DataContract/DataMember attributes

Comment: Did you have any issues with serialization ? Especially regarding navigatonal properties, and issues with the dynamic proxy not being serialized.

Comment: With EF 4.1, it's a little different, for the property fetch of the .tt, you have to add [DataMember] before the line who starts by : <#=accessibility#> <#=type#> <#=name#>

Comment: I had to use `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` because I was getting stuff like this in the logs: `...contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled`

Comment: is there anyway to edit the DbContext Code generated template, to include datacontract and datamember attribute so that I can use in data model in my WCF (SOAP) service?

Comment: Helped me a lot!. However it was quite different for EF6, add `[DataContract]` above line# 27 and `[DataMember]` above line# 72. Also add using `System.Runtime.Serialization;` for using block.

Answer (score 1):

In EF6.1 you need to edit the model1.tt and add tag between UsingDirectives and EntityClassOpening:

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false)#>
//MY TAG:
[Serializable]
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
```