# How to add wcf attributes in poco template that is applicable in Complex Type?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4, poco

I use the instructions from [Adding [DataMember] [DataContract] attributes in Entity Framework POCO Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678121/adding-datamember-datacontract-attributes-in-entity-framework-poco-template)

At first it worked, all of my complex types are generated with wcf attributed [DataContract] [DataMember].  And then when I regenerate, I don't know why all of my Complex Types have no [DataContract] [DataMember]. Only the entities have [DataContract][DataMember]

```
[DataContract]
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{
<#
    region.Begin("Primitive Properties");

    foreach (EdmProperty edmProperty in entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == entity))
    {
        bool isForeignKey = entity.NavigationProperties.Any(np=>np.GetDependentProperties().Contains(edmProperty));
        bool isDefaultValueDefinedInModel = (edmProperty.DefaultValue != null);
        bool generateAutomaticProperty = false;



#>

    [DataMember]
    <#=PropertyVirtualModifier(Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty))#> <#=code.Escape(edmProperty.TypeUsage)#> <#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#>
    {









//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
<#=String.Join(String.Empty, extraUsings.Select(u => "using " + u + ";" + Environment.NewLine).ToArray())#>
<#+
    fileManager.EndBlock();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code, also is it possible for you to go back o the point at which it worked?

Comment: i edited my question and posted my code. I tried to go back to which it worked, but I couldn't. I even tried to delete the t4 template and re-do it, but it did not work.

Comment: Please edit your question down to a reasonable length. Only post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the following extension? 
It is for EF5 and VS 2012, but there is also an equivalent for EF 4.x.

[image]

It allows to generate POCOs already decorated with WCF attributes without having to customize the template.