# DataMember and DataContract attributes for DBContext template

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, dbcontext

I just started a project using EF. In VS 2012 the default template for edm model is now DBContext code generated template. I've searched a lot but could not find clarification anywhere on how to use WCF with DbContext. I need to build a WCF Service (not a WCF data service), so my questions are:

1. Do I have to add WCF DataContract/DataMember attributes to serialize. How should I use DBContext with WCF (I am not using any DTOs). I will send POCOs generated from DBContext template across the wire.
2. If I have to add attributes is there any way to modify the template to automaticaly add DataMember/DataContract attributes like they do [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678121/adding-datamember-datacontract-attributes-in-entity-framework-poco-template)?

Answer (score 1):

DBContext is used for entity to entity mapping.
And it is used to save the data in to the database. But if you want to pass out then you just create a prtail class and then Metadatatype and then you can customize that entity and then you can send it.

Please look the Metadatatype in entity framework.

Comment: thanks for reply! Sorry I am quite at beginner level with EF so I didn't understand completely your answer, As I mentioned that if I am going to build a WCF (SOAP) service with database first approach, didn't I need to add datacontract/datamember attributes to POCO? classes or serialization will work even without these attributes?

Comment: Do you want to serilize the POCO class.

Comment: As above i have mention that you can do it but you have to apply the datacontract/datamember attributes on that.

Comment: are there any other problems with serialization and using dbcontext, or if I just apply wcf attributes it will work

Comment: No...BDBcontext is not use for serilization. Poco class don't have [Serializable()] attribute it. If you have added then it will work or you are generating the POCO from any tools which ads the [Serializable()] attribute then it will works

Comment: I am just using DbContext code generated T4 template to create classes

Answer (score 0):

I managed to edit the template using [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678121/adding-datamember-datacontract-attributes-in-entity-framework-poco-template), as I am using Entity 4.x not EF 5. The only difference in template was mentioned by [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287824/eka808) in comments in [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678121/adding-datamember-datacontract-attributes-in-entity-framework-poco-template).