# Is their a way to generate POCOs with DataAnnotation attributes applied to the POCOs?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF5.

Does a visual studio template exists which can generate POCOs having appropriate attributes applied to them from the DataAnnotations namespace (like Key and Foreign Key)

I can generate POCOs using the EF 5.x DBContext Generator which utilizes an existing Entity Data Model,  but then I have to manually go setup the Keys and Foreign keys.

For a larger data model this is a pain!

Comment: What we have done on our last project was to modify the TT script to add data annotations and other properties on the objects. It is not difficult to do.

Comment: That is awesome.  Do you have any code you can share?    Save a guy some time :-)

Comment: Dont have any code that will help you out but check out these two articles they will get you on the right track.
http://onlinecoder.blogspot.ca/2011/03/customize-entity-framework-code.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678121/adding-datamember-datacontract-attributes-in-entity-framework-poco-template

Comment: I found several T4 templates - all modified to add DataAnnotations EXCEPT Key and ForeignKey.   :-(.

Comment: Did you define the Primary key and ForeignKey on your model diagram?

Comment: The keys are already defined in the database so when the data model is generated it uses the database defined keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly for me - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d