# EntityFramework database first exposing generated class as Datacontract

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontract, edmx-designer

I made a webservice which is supposed to return an entity 'UserProfile'. Most operations return the expected result but I get empty responses when I directly return a generated class.

Service:

```
List<UserProfile> IMusicOwnerService.getProfiles()
    {
        return context.UserProfileSet.ToList();
    }
```

Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:getProfiles/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I modified the Model.tt file ( [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678121/adding-datamember-datacontract-attributes-in-entity-framework-poco-template) )
then this class was generated:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;  //Template modification test
    [DataContract]//Template modification test
    public partial class UserProfile
    {

        public UserProfile()
        {
            this.LoginSession = new HashSet<LoginSession>();
            this.Playlist = new HashSet<Playlist>();
            this.Friends = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
            this.Song = new HashSet<Song>();
        }

        [DataMember]//Template modification test
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]//Template modification test
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]//Template modification test
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember]//Template modification test
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DataMember]//Template modification test
        public string Salt { get; set; }

}
```

No response when sending the request.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCEOe.jpg
(not enough reputation to post pictures)