# How not hide certain fields in the exposed object type for WCF client?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, datacontract

We are autogenerating our model using EF and when an exposed method uses it, the creation of the proxy client creates the corresponding object type for us.

So, if the WCF has a method signature and type as follows, **all the fields** are being presented in intellisense when working with said object.

```
class Thing
{
  public int Wanted { get; set; }
  public int Unwanted { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
public Thing GetSomething() { ... }
```

This far, we've been using a custom made model using it in our clients namespace definitions. However, it means that we need to manually create a bunch of properties attributed *DataMember* and the maintenance is a pain.

Is it possible to control which autogenerated fields that are exposed so that when we create a web reference to a service that exposes *GetSomething*, it only shows those we want? Of course, we still want to build up the model structure on server side using EF so that we simply can regenerate the model when changes to the DB are made.

Comment: What about when EF generate your classes, it add DataMember attributes? Even if you use a custom class for your service, it will be probably based in you EF generated class, so if you use a custom template (.tt file) can save your time.
Here you can see if this solution can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678121/adding-datamember-datacontract-attributes-in-entity-framework-poco-template

Comment: @RicardoPontual I was thinking along the lines of text transforms (or text template or whatever TT stands for here) but I wasn't sure if it's the best course of action. But given that you're mentioning it, maybe it wasn't so far fetched... You might want to post the comment as a reply so I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about when EF generate your classes, it add **DataMember** attributes?

Even if you use a custom class for your service, it will be probably based in you EF generated class, so if you use a T4 custom template (.tt file) can save your time. Here you can see if this solution can help you:

[Adding [DataMember] [DataContract] attributes in Entity Framework POCO Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678121/adding-datamember-datacontract-attributes-in-entity-framework-poco-template)

Hope it helps.