# adding ASPxGridView to page with ObjectDataSource programmatically

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm trying to add `ASPxGridView` to page and bind it to `ObjectDataSource` programmatically.

here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectDataSource odsGroup = new ObjectDataSource();
        var gridLookup = new ASPxGridView();

        odsGroup.ID = "odsGroups";
        odsGroup.SelectMethod = "GetAllElements";
        odsGroup.TypeName = "Ifa.BusinessLayer.BLLClasses.GroupBll";
        odsGroup.OldValuesParameterFormatString = "original_{0}";

        gridLookup.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled;


        gridLookup.ID = "groupsLookup";
        gridLookup.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        gridLookup.DataSource = odsGroup;
        gridLookup.KeyFieldName = "Id";
        gridLookup.DataBind();
        pnl1.Controls.Add(gridLookup);
    }
```

This code works fine when i use `GridView` instead of `ASPxGridView`, but as I said it does not work with `ASPxGridView` and throws `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException`

exception:
[image]

any solutions?

Comment: Try setting grid EnableViewState to false. If that doesn't help try marking [IfaEntities1 with Serializable attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756592/entity-framework-4-0-autogenerated-classes-not-marked-as-serializable).

Comment: I've check your solution, they did not worked. after making IfaEntities1 I've got Type exception 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' in Assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Try binding grid to EntityDatasource (I assumed you are using Entity framework). [Example from DevEx site](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3251.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
  gridLookup.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn("Name"));
  gridLookup.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be related to the IIS's secure settings and corresponding permissions. ASPxGridView deserializes data rows from its cache when it's necessary. Disable the ASPxGridView's cache by setting the **ASPxGridView.EnableRowsCache** property to "**False**".